# Angularjs three state checkbox with ng-repeat issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to get a list of questions (retrieved dynamically so we can't hard code them) and then using `ng-repeat` list them out with a three state checkbox next to each (`true`, `false`, `null`).

The code below works to show the questions with the correct checkboxes, however each time you click on 1 checkbox they all change as they are using the same `ng-model` (I assume).

How do I get around this?

Thanks

```
<div class="select-all-checkboxes" flex="100" ng-repeat="(guidCustomerId,item) in items" ng-if="item.type=='Mandatory'">
    <span three-state-checkbox ng-model="idv.checkboxModelThree" ng-change="idv.checkBoxonChange()" ng-checked="exists(item, selected_mandatory)"></span>
    <h8-red>{{item.question}}</h8-red>{{item.answer}}
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried something like `ng-model="item.value" ng-change="item.value = ! item.value"`?

Comment: ng-change="item.value = item.value" did the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try?

```
<div class="select-all-checkboxes" flex="100" ng-repeat="(guidCustomerId,item) in items" ng-if="item.type=='Mandatory'">
    <span three-state-checkbox ng-model="item.value" ng-change="item.value = !item.value" ng-checked="exists(item, selected_mandatory)"></span>
    <h8-red>{{item.question}}</h8-red>{{item.answer}}
    <br /><br />
</div>
```